# Apple Watch Companion App: sendMessage doesn't work with quit iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, apple-watch

I'm currently building an Apple Watch Companion App with Swift and Flutter. I'm doing this with the help of [theamorn's Github project](https://github.com/theamorn/fluttter-apple-watch). Everything works in the simulator (iOS 15.0 and WatchOS 8.0), even if the iOS App is force quit. However, when testing on my AW Series 3 (WatchOS 8.0) and iPhone 11 (iOS 15.0) it will only work, as long as the iOS App is opened.

My **AppDelegate.swift** of the **iOS App**

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import WatchConnectivity

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var session: WCSession?
    let methodChannelName: String = "app.controller.watch"
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      initFlutterChannel()
      if WCSession.isSupported() {
          session = WCSession.default;
          session!.delegate = self;
          session!.activate();
      }
      
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    private func initFlutterChannel() {
          if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
            let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
              name: methodChannelName,
              binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
            
            channel.setMethodCallHandler({ [weak self] (
              call: FlutterMethodCall,
              result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
              switch call.method {
                case "flutterToWatch":
                   guard let watchSession = self?.session, watchSession.isPaired,
                      watchSession.isReachable, let methodData = call.arguments as? [String: Any],
                      let method = methodData["method"], let data = methodData["data"] as? Any else {
                      result(false)
                   return
                   }
                
                   let watchData: [String: Any] = ["method": method, "data": data]
                   watchSession.sendMessage(watchData, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
                   result(true)
                default:
                   result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                }
             })
           }
        }
}

extension AppDelegate: WCSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        
    }
    
    func sessionReachabilityDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("Watch reachability: \(session.isReachable)")
        if (session.isReachable) {
            //invoke sendWakeupToFlutter via MethodChannel when reachability is true
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
                    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
                        name: self.methodChannelName,
                        binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
                    channel.invokeMethod("sendWakeupToFlutter", arguments: [])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        
    }
    
    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let method = message["method"] as? String, let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
                let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
                    name: self.methodChannelName,
                    binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
                channel.invokeMethod(method, arguments: message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My **WatchViewModel.swift** in my **Watch Extension**

```swift
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var session: WCSession
    var deviceList: String = ""
    @Published var loading: Bool = false
    @Published var pubDeviceList: [Device]?
    
    // Add more cases if you have more receive method
    enum WatchReceiveMethod: String {
        case sendLoadingStateToNative
        case sendSSEDeviceListToNative
    }
    
    // Add more cases if you have more sending method
    enum WatchSendMethod: String {
        case sendWakeupToFlutter
        case sendCloseToFlutter
    }
    
    init(session: WCSession = .default) {
        self.session = session
        super.init()
        self.session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
    
    func sendDataMessage(for method: WatchSendMethod, data: [String: Any] = [:]) {
        sendMessage(for: method.rawValue, data: data)
    }
    
}

extension WatchViewModel: WCSessionDelegate {
    
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        
    }
    
    func sessionReachabilityDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("iPhone reachability: \(session.isReachable)")
        if(session.isReachable) {
            //invoke sendWakeupToFlutter via sendMessage when reachability is true
            sendDataMessage(for: .sendWakeupToFlutter)
        }
    }
    
    // Receive message From AppDelegate.swift that send from iOS devices
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            guard let method = message["method"] as? String, let enumMethod = WatchReceiveMethod(rawValue: method) else {
                return
            }
            
            switch enumMethod {
                case .sendLoadingStateToNative:
                    self.loading = (message["data"] as? Bool) ?? false
                case .sendSSEDeviceListToNative:
                    self.deviceList = (message["data"] as? String) ?? ""

                    let data = self.deviceList.data(using: .utf8)!
                    do {
                        self.pubDeviceList = try JSONDecoder().decode([Device].self, from: data)
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sendMessage(for method: String, data: [String: Any] = [:]) {
        guard session.isReachable else {
            print("ios not reachable")
            return
        }
        print("ios is reachable")
        let messageData: [String: Any] = ["method": method, "data": data]
        let callDepth = 10
        session.sendMessage(messageData, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
The change in my watch extension so far:

```swift
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        if (activationState == WCSessionActivationState.activated) {
            sendDataMessage(for: .sendWakeupToFlutter)
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** The accepted answer didn't solve my problem entirely, but improved the situation. I ended up making a rather independent Watch App w/o using Flutter MethodChannels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably won't fix your issue but you should be careful about using `session.isReachable` - its value is only valid for a session that is `activated`, which it almost certainly is (activate session is async but quick I think), but WatchOS has a number of APIs where the value can only be trusted if certain conditions are met, and you should check, otherwise you end up with a value like true or false when the real value should be 'don't know'

IIRC `isReachable` is normally true from watch to counterpart iPhone app, you should consider sending the wake up proactively when the session activates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time! I already execute `sendMessage` twice as I also execute it in `onAppear` of my main SwiftUI-View (executing it again in the `sessionReachabilityDidChange`was just a desperate try to fix the bug ) - or is there another way to proactively wake up the iOS App apart from sending `sendMessage`?

Comment: You can also wake the iOS companion by updating its application context but that’s just another kind of messaging. activationDidCompleteWith… is the place to try waking the phone, onAppear is likely too early, and you need to check the activationState value is .activated

Comment: Hi, I've tested it and now it works in roughly 3/5 cases. Interestingly, it never works when my phone is locked. I'm currently having a look at `iOSDeviceNeedsUnlockAfterRebootForReachability` - have you experienced sth. similar? 
Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it 

The code change can bee seen in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** It should probably work when the quit app was built for release.

**Long Version**
I had the same issue. What I found out is that it works fine when building the flutter app in release mode (rather than just running it via XCode/non release mode).

The reason for that is that, when opening a quit app that wasn't built for release, you'll see the screen that you need to run it via a Flutter IDE or XCode. Which indicates that the app is not properly launched when trying to launch a non-release app via the home screen. That is why the message that is being sent from the watch will probably not reach the iOS WCSession or make it through the platform channel.